# find minimum bottleneck path in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

consider we have a complete graph with n vertexes. Each vertex has a value. weight of the edge between two vertexes i and j is equal to value[i] xor value[j].
the question is to find a path from vertex 1 to vertex n which the maximum of weighes of edges in the path is minimum. I already modified Dijkstra's algorithm and found an algorithm of O(n ^ 2 lg(n)). can someone help me find a more efficient algorithm?

Comment: Do you mean O(n * log n)?  Or O(n^(log n))?

Comment: @templatetypedef I think he means O(n * n * logn)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimum bottleneck value cannot be less than the number determined by the most significant bit (`M`) of this value: `value[1] XOR value[n]`. If you find two nodes `A` and `B`, such that `M` and higher bits of nodes `1` and `A` are equal as well as equal are `M` and higher bits of nodes `n` and `B`, with minimal edge weight between `A` and `B`, the minimum bottleneck path would be 1-A-B-n (or it may be shorter if A=1 and/or B=n).

To choose `A/B` pair with minimal edge weight, construct a binary trie for all node values with high order bits (`M` and higher) coinciding with node `1`. Then for all node values with high order bits coinciding with node `n`, try to search these values in this trie. If exact match is not found, choose deepest partial match.

Time complexity is O(n * M).